# Select values from a list that aren't in a table?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'd like to do something like the following; what's the easiest way?

```
SELECT id FROM (1,2,3) WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table)
```

The idea is not to increase memory usage of my python script by loading table IDs into the script first.
The only way I can think of is to build a temporary table using the WITH query, which is a little verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id from (values (1),(2),(3)) as s(id)
except
select id from table
```

To do it with Psycopg:

```
id_list = ['1','2','3']
q = """
    select array_agg(id)
    from (
        select id from (values {}) s(id)
        except
        select id from table
    ) t;
""".format(','.join(['%s'] * len(id_list)))

print cur.mogrify(q, [(id,) for id in id_list])
# cur.execute(q, [(id,) for id in id_list])
```

Output:

```
select array_agg(id)
from (
    select id from (values ('1'),('2'),('3')) s(id)
    except
    select id from table
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

provided answer works like a charm, but I couldn't get it to work with psycopg2 built in string formatting because each value needs parenthesis in the provided answer, not sure there is a way around that besides building the query string manually.

```
q = "select id from (values %s as s(id)
except
select id from table"
cur.execute(q, (id_list,))
```

the following is an alternative that works since psycopg2 has python list > postgres array converter

```
select array_agg(ids)
from (
  select unnest(ARRAY['1', '2'])
  except
  select unnest(array_agg(sku::text)) from table
) t (ids);
```